# With JQuery UI's datepicker, is it possible to change the format of the years in the dropdown for the "changeYear" option?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have the ability to set month names with the monthNames option, so if I set changeMonth to true it shows the names that I provided. Can I provide a format for the years listed when I set changeYear to true?

For example, if I want to show a 2 digit year instead of 4, is this possible? And if so, how do I do it? I do not see it anywhere in the JQuery UI Datepicker docs, so I am hoping that I have just missed it.
https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Where do you want to see the two digit year? In an input field or on the datepicker itself?

Comment: On the datepicker in the year dropdown.